# Why are inputs in the list getting overwritten

Tags: python-3.x, list

Code at the moment :

```py
List=list()
while True:
    print(
        'a.   Add a new record'
        'b.   Display all employees'
        'c.   Exit'
    )
    option=input("Enter an option")

    if option == "a" :
        sur= input("enter surname")
        fir = input("enter firstname")
        List.append(sur)
        List.append(fir)

    elif option == "b" :
        for x in empList:
            print("firstname :" , fir)
            print("surname :" , sur)

    elif option == "c" :
        break;
```

Every time i choose to enter a new record and then choose the option to display it, the previous set of names get overwritten.
Im not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing gets "overwritten". The problem is that you are using names `sur` and `fir` which are bound to the last iteration of the loop in the `"a"` command. They might not even exist; if you try to display all before inputting a first name you will get a `NameError` exception.

The display part of the code should look like

```
elif option == "b":
    for x in empList:
        print(x)
```

Then you will discover another problem with the logic. The "adding" part of your code adds the first and surnames individually. There is no relation between a person's first and surname, except for the fact that they are in adjacent indexes. This might not be a strong enough relation.

Instead of

```
empList.append(sur)
empList.append(fir)
```

you should probably do

```
empList.append((sur, fir))
```

which will insert each person to the list as a tuple.

Comment: How does appending it with two parentheses store it into the list as a tuple?

Comment: `(sur, fir)` is a tuple, so `.append((sur, fir))` appends that tuple.